# Magento 1.8 - cart lifetime

Tags: php, magento, cart, shopping-cart, lifetime

I would like to keep products in cart for e.g. 1 hour, for both logged in and not logged in users.
So, for example, if last product was added to cart at 15:50, when user comes back at 16:51 the cart should be empty.
I have seen configuration options such as *Persistent Shopping Cart* or `checkout_cart_delete_quote_after` but they do not fit my needs.

Any help is much appreciated. I am not looking for solution, I just need some tips and I would like to know general concept how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to limit session life time and set cookie expiration to 1h?